# C++ What is the difference between 2 functions: one iterates with iterators the other uses indexes

Tags: c++

I want to know why these 2 ways of writing the same code are taking different times.

**Method 1:**

```
int function(vector<int>& rooms)
{
    for(int i:rooms)
    {
        if(i>=target)
            return i;
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
int function(vector<int>& rooms)
{    
    int n=rooms.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(rooms[i]>=target)
            return rooms[i];
    }
}
```

The 1st method seems to be taking considerably more time than the 2nd method every time. I don't understand why though. Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: "*The 1st method seems to be taking considerably more time than the 2nd method*" - I seriously doubt that. The difference between the two codes is basically iterators vs indexes, and `vector` iterators are very light-weight with almost no overhead. And same with `vector::size()` and `vector:operator[]`. So, the two approaches should have very close times. What are you using exactly to time this code?

Comment: Did you compile with full optimization in both cases?

Comment: Are you measuring with an optimized build? (i.e. not debug)

Comment: What does "considerably more time" mean? And are you compiling with optimizations enabled? P.S. They are logically identical.

Comment: Perhaps unrelated: Your programs have a potential _undefined behavior_. If no `rooms[i]>=target` is found, none of the functions will return an `int`.

Comment: what kind of Object is room and what is target?

Comment: @femimcpd We can clearly see what `rooms` is - a `vector<int>&`.  And `target` would have to be something that is implicitly convertible to `int`. I don't think the types of `rooms` and `target` are particularly relevant to this issue.

Comment: probably your benchmark isn't very good

Comment: @JimWlad, Please show us more data: (A)  What is the size of the vector ? (1 million or 100 million elements ?).  (B) What is the time it takes to complete each of the 2 methods ? (1 minute vs 2 minutes ?)

Comment: @femimcpd The types used are not a mystery but I do think that a [mre] would have made the question better. I think Remy makes a relevant observation. Making things "irrelevant" is part of finding the real issue.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you should take your won advice

Comment: @femimcpd I hope I do - but if I've failed, please point it out and I'll try to improve.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no problem

Comment: @femimcpd Will that happen soon?

Answer (score 1):

The first version makes copies of each element of the vector. (This may or may not be optimized out).

Try

```
for(const int& i: rooms)
```

Comment: Since the element is an `int`, it is very unlikely that copying it is slower than using a reference. This would be significant if it was a more complicated object that was being copied.

Comment: @pcarter - well, godbolt shows identical code: https://godbolt.org/z/eEjxEnzbE . However, this is a good habit to have for iterating over containers.

Comment: Assuming your intent is read-only. That advice is too generalized, and `const auto&` would be better still.